# (UDP) GVCP BroadCast not functioning

Tags: udp, winsock

Environment: Windows Socket Programming using VC++ 2010

GVCP : GigE Vision Control Protocol

GVCP = UDP+(GVCP Header Data+Payload Data). so basically on top its a UDP only

for Detecting GigE Sensor (Camera)  need to first Broadcast a GVCP packet (containing Gvcp Payload data), using Broadcast address 255.255.255.255

but i am able to broadcast only by 192.168.1.255 (as seen on wire-shark) when i change broadcast address 255.255.255.255 nothing is visible on wire-shark nor on other machine

**so problem is  not able to broadcast using IP 255.255.255.255 using UDP/WinSock**

Answer (score 0):

able to start broadcasting the GVCP packet its just a  socket creation error the correct one is below

```
//---------------------DATA SENDER------------------------------
        struct sockaddr_in Sender_addr;
        int     Sender_addrlen      =   sizeof(Sender_addr);    
        Sender_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        Sender_addr.sin_port        = htons(CAMPORT);               //BROADCAST_PORT);
        Sender_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("255.255.255.255"); //Broadcast 
    IP Here");



//---------------------DATA RECEIVER----------------------------
        struct sockaddr_in Recv_addr;
        int     Recv_addrlen        =   sizeof(Recv_addr);
        Recv_addr.sin_family        = AF_INET;
        Recv_addr.sin_port          = htons(PCPORT);
        Recv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr   = INADDR_ANY;

        if(bind(sock,(sockaddr*)&Recv_addr,sizeof(Recv_addr))<0)    
        {
            perror("bind");
            _getch;
            closesocket(sock);
        }

//and then send command for GVCP packet (GVCP packet Structure is )

        TxBuff[0]   =   0x42;   
        TxBuff[1]   =   0x01;       
        TxBuff[2]   =   0x00;   
        TxBuff[3]   =   0x02;
        TxBuff[4]   =   0x00;   
        TxBuff[5]   =   0x00;
        TxBuff[6]   =   0x00;   
        TxBuff[7]   =   0x02;

    if(sendto(sock,TxBuff,TxBuffSize,0,(struct sockaddr 
    *)&Sender_addr,sizeof(Sender_addr)) <0)
                {
                perror("send: error ");
                _getch();
                closesocket(sock);            
            }
```